# Manual of the angles tikzlibrary

Tags: tikz-pgf, documentation, tikz-angles

I would like to learn some commands of the angles `tikzlibrary`.
I have been looking on the internet for its manual but so far I couldn't find any documentation.
Can anybody help me please?
Thank you so much!

Comment: See section 39 of the [`pgf` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). Also, another package you can use to draw/label angles (general geometry, actually) is [`tkz-euclide`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide).

Comment: Thank you! I am at section 39 of the pgf manual but it is about the Matrix library. I heard about the tkz-euclide, it looks very promising but the manual is in French only and so I can't understand it, unfortunately.

Comment: No, in the manual I linked (for version 3.0.1a), the `angles` library is in section 39 (p. 511), while the `matrix` library is in section 57 (p. 646). You are looking at an old version of the manual (version 2.10 is my guess). Follow the link in my first comment, it takes you directly to the most up-to-date manual.

Comment: Got it! I was using an old manual. Thank you!

Comment: if you scroll through the `tkz-euclide` manual, you will find that the examples at the end are mainly in English.

Comment: I have just voted to close this because angles are well documented in the `tikz and `tikz-euclide` manuals and this is too long to reproduce here.